# AsyncFileUpload - the file attached is invalid

Tags: asp.net, asyncfileupload

I am getting an error when I upload an image with the asyncfileupload control.

I get the error 'the file attached is invalid'.

On my local machine this works fine, but it doesn't work on my live server.

I tried the fix that says to put the ClientIDMode="AutoID" on the control with no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

check that you have rights on the files on both server and client. also check the path string you are setting for reading and writing file